# android list view layout animation on scroll and on show

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, animation

I want to make a simple slide in from left animation in my list view.

I tried using

```
android:layoutAnimation = "@anim/my_layout_animation"
```

for my list view but it only animates visible items and the remaining items in he list don't get animated

I also tried adding animations on getView

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view  = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (! flags[position]){
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_right_in);
            view.setAnimation(animation);
            flags[position] = true;
        }
        return view;
    }
```

but then the first visible items had the same animation in the same time without delay.

Comment: try removing the if condition

Comment: @Greengoblin the if condition is to make it show the animation for the first time only

Comment: When the scroll is done, getView will again be called on that row. So, animation won't be played.

Comment: yes and that is intended to play the animation the first time it shows up

Answer (score 0):

try starting the animation:

```
 view.startAnimation(animation);
```